# Can I charge my 19.5 V laptop with a 19V power bank?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I have a laptop of which the regular power supply provides 19.5V at 3.34A.
I am thinking about buying an external power bank that I can choose between 19 or 20 V.

Would this be safe to use?
Should I also take the battery of the laptop into account or if I match the power supply to the power bank it should be fine?

Thank you so uch for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a power bank work as a laptop battery alternative?](//superuser.com/q/834679)

Comment: 19.5V is close enough to both 19V and 20V that either would work. Generally, it's better to slightly overvoltage than undervoltage because undervoltage means overcurrent. So I'd pick the 20V bank.

Comment: To answer your last question, the battery voltage and charger voltage will be very different.  The laptop contains circuitry to do what it needs with the charger voltage.  The battery voltage won't be useful information for this question.  Just look at the power adapter you will be replacing.

Comment: BTW, make sure the current rating matches.  Another consideration for whether you can do it is how it connects.  Some brands of laptops check whether the power source is OEM.  So even if the ratings and connectors match, it may not work, or may charge very slowly.  If the power pack provides an AC outlet, that would allow you to plug the OEM adapter into it.  So to get a reliable answer, you need to identify your laptop and the type of power pack you're talking about.